# How to concatenate double with string in field calculator with Python expression?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, python, field-calculator

I'd like to concatenate my lat/lng with a few string fields in ArcGIS. What is the correct expression to use, avoiding VBA.  I don't want to convert the lat/lng fields to string either.

my 4 fields are category, type, x, y. with x and y being doubles.

Answer (score 4):

using python field calculator, you can use

```
str(!lat!) + !yourStringField!
```

or you can use the [format](http://mkaz.com/2012/10/10/python-string-format/)() function for more control (in this case, 2 decimal places).

```
"""lat is {:.2f}, long is {:.2f} for city {}""".format(!lat!,!long!,!citiyName!)
```

of course the field where you do the concatenation must be a text field

Comment: For labeling or similar, yes, but that won't work in a field calculator and still keep x and y as doubles.
Edit: although the OP's question is unclear. Your method will work to calculate a new string field, leaving the original x and y values as doubles. I read it as meaning the new field would consist of mixed types.

Comment: Thank you for the precision ,but X an Y can remain double, only the field where you do the concatenation must be text field. Otherwise I agree with you that it is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

You can't. A field is a defined data type - double, text, float, etc. You can't have a field that's a mixed data type You can have python data structures that consist of mixed data types, such as a list, but this isn't the same as a field in a table. If this was just for labeling, there are several ways to do this, but as far as field calculation, no.

Edit: see my reply in comments, the question is unclear, to me at least.

Comment: The objective was to just concatenate the 4 fields to a new text field.  @Radouxju's suggestion worked